# How can PostgreSQL use multi-column index for column-specific lookups?

Tags: postgresql, index

If I'm reading [this article](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-indexes/postgresql-multicolumn-indexes/) correctly, one can create an index on `t(col1, col2)` and use it to speed up lookups for `col1`. Storage and CPU-wise, I assume that having such a combined index is more efficient than having two indexes. From this perspective, how does PostgreSQL build a map of the indexed data in a way that allows such single-column queries? In other words, what algorithms and/or data structures enable that?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: could you point me to the section that answers my question?

Answer (score 1):

No map needs to be built.

A multi-column index can be thought of as a list that is ordered as follows:

```
 col1 | col2
------+------
    1 |    1   \
    1 |    3    \--> for all entries with col1 = 1, sort by col2
    1 |    4    /
    1 |   42   /
    3 |    1   \
    3 |    2    \
    3 |    2     |--> for all entries with col1 = 3, sort by col2
    3 |    5    /
    3 |   12   /
    4 |    2
    4 |    7
...
```

Now an index can be used if all the values you want to scan lie next to each other in the index.

Now if you want to find the rows `WHERE col1 = 42`, you find them right next to each other in the index. So the index can be used for such a condition.

It is different for the condition `WHERE col2 = 1`. Here the index cannot be used, because the entries with `col2 = 1` are spread all over the index.

Comment: So basically PostgreSQL doesn't allow to look up by col2 if index is on (col1, col2)?

Comment: That has nothing to do with "allow". It just cannot be used effectively. Look at the list I sketched in my answer. How can you use a list that is sorted in this way to find all entries with `col2 = 1`? There is no way but to read the whole list. Then you might as well scan the whole table. So using the index offers no advantage.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Sounds like I misunderstood the documentation and having an index on (col1, col2) will also optimize queries by col1, but not by col2 then, leaving them as seq_scan. No idea where I got the misunderstanding from.